# Java library which can generate charts from sql

Tags: java, sql, charts, weblogic

I have weblogic where I can deploy this java application and database where I have data. Can you recommend me some free java library which can generate charts from my data ?
I found http://oreports.com/ but their forum seems to be inactive for a long time so when I want to advice I have problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this: http://art.sourceforge.net/ which is exactly what I need

Answer (score 4):

Try out [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports).

Answer (score 1):

[List of open source options](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting) for generating reports in java.

I personally recommend JasperReports.

Comment: but I need web based java aplication which I can deploy to weblogic and I dont see that this can handle jasper

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nothing like presenting charts from data directly without any java app. (So no informatica like tools) `jfreechart` is an option. have a lookt at `fusion-charts` too